# where does 404 page of jetty locate at?

Tags: jersey, jetty, http-status-code-404

I built a restful service using jetty and jersey. When jersey return 404 response, jetty will return a 404 web page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /test/404page. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

But, I want nothing except for a 404 status code. I want to delete the default 404 page, but I can't found where does it locate at. What should I do?

Comment: Note: Jetty 9.3.8+ includes a Request header `Accept` check before returning an HTML based error Response content. See [PR #385](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/pull/385)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set the following Jersey property to `true`

> [`ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR)

This will make it so that only the status code is sent, and not the error page.